# this principled shader node cant be shown in blender 2.78?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

As you can see appears "undefined" the PBT Principled shader node from blender 2.79, and I need to use it.

Is there a way or other alternative for rendering PBR Textures with all the same input settings that this shader has?

[image]

Comment: Please keep all extraneous text out of posts. Principled shader was introduced in 2.79 and is not compatible with previous versions

Comment: It's probably a good one... but what's your reason for not using 2.79?

Comment: @RobinBetts unfortunately i cant use it in my os

Comment: What OS does not allow you to use V2.79?

Comment: @Sprad001 its complicated to explain :"(

Answer (score 3):

The principled BSDF shader was introduced in version 2.79. Previous versions of blender will not be able to use such node.

You would need to recreate the properties of a Physically Based Shader using a combination of other shader.

There are quite a few "tutorials" out there that show how to do this. Here are some links:

https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/pbr-shader-tutorial-pt1?rq=pbr

and

https://meshlogic.github.io/posts/blender/materials/nodes-pbr-basic-shader/

but there are plenty of others you can find using your favorite search engine.